# JT400 SpooledFile to TIFF zoom level

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jtopen

I am trying to convert AFPDS spooled files to TIFF images. No problem, unless the original spooled file spills outside the printable area. In the iSeries Navigator, I can zoom out and see the content that spilled over. I am desperately seeking a method to do the same with the JT400 toolkit. Does anyone have a hint?

V6R1, a simplified version of the code follows:

```
    private void readTiffs(SpooledFile spf) throws AS400Exception, AS400SecurityException, ErrorCompletingRequestException, IOException, InterruptedException, RequestNotSupportedException{
    PrintParameterList prtParm = new PrintParameterList();
    PrintObjectPageInputStream inpStream = null;

    prtParm.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_MFGTYPE,"*WSCST" );
    prtParm.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_WORKSTATION_CUST_OBJECT, "/QSYS.LIB/QWPTIFFPB.WSCST");

    inpStream = spf.getPageInputStream(prtParm);

    if(inpStream != null) {
        byte[] imagebuff = null;
        do{
              imagebuff = new byte[inpStream.available()];
              inpStream.read (imagebuff);

              // we have the TIFF here, but the right side is cut off if the printout overflowed

        } while(inpStream.nextPage());
    }
}
```

Thanks,
John

Comment: What do you want the end result to be?  Let's say you have a 198 column wide spooled file and you're converting it to an 8 inch wide TIFF.  At 10 CPI, that would be 80 columns of image, cutting off 9.8 inches off of the right side of the image.  Are you trying to create a second TIFF file consisting of those chopped off 9.8 inches?  Or are you trying to dynamically size the TIFF file so that it is wide enough to encompass the entire width of the page?

Comment: I want to get all of the data. Is there some way using SpooledFile.getPageInputStream to determine the width and then specify it? This isn't a text only file, it includes barcodes and bitmaps. In the AFP viewer in iSeries Navigator there is a red rectangle defining the margins of an 8.5x11 page that outline exactly what the TIFF image ends up containing.